# Mapping Kafka to Spark dataFrame with the Schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have application which runs query on Kafka topics with the schema specified,
Below is my code :

```
  SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Spark-Kafka-Integration")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "abc:9092,bcs:9092")
                .option("subscribe","topic")
                .option("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp")
                .load();
        // Mapping it to the schema
        Dataset<Row> ds2 =  df.select( from_json(col("value").cast("string")  , Kafkaschema).as("rows"),col("timestamp"));

        ds2.createOrReplaceTempView("ds2");

        // Making a Row having timestamp and the values
        Dataset<Row> ds3 = spark.sql("select rows.* , timestamp from ds2 ");

        ds3.createOrReplaceTempView("table");
        Dataset<Row> result2 = spark.sql(query.getQuery());
```

This runs fine, now I have view `table` which will have all columns and timestamp. Then I can run SQL like `Select column1 , column2 from table group by window(timestamp,'1 minutes'),column1 , column2`

My Question :

Is this is an efficient way to do it ? Because if I have multiple topics i.e  `.option("subscribe","topic1,topics2,...")`  then I have to create multiple data frame in order to run Join Query on them and how I can handle timestamp column ?

In case of multiple topics I will have the following code :

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark
                    .readStream()
                    .format("kafka")
                    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "abc:9092,bcs:9092")
                    .option("subscribe","topic1, topic2,....topicn")
                    .option("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
                    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp")
                    .load();
 Dataset<Row> ds =  df.select( from_json(col("value").cast("string")  , Kafkaschema).as("rows"),col("timestamp")).where("topic=topic1");
  Dataset<Row> ds1 =  df.select( from_json(col("value").cast("string")  , Kafkaschema).as("rows"),col("timestamp")).where("topic=topic2");
.... so on and have to same for other data frame
```

Comment: Efficient way to do what? Unclear what you're joining on. The code you've posted only subscribes to one topic. Timestamp column is the same, regardless of the number of topics

Comment: Code is for single topic, I am asking if there are multiple topics so how i can do this efficiently so in the end I can have SQL joining these topics i.e `Select column1 , column2, column3....column_n  from table1,table2,table3.... group by window(timestamp,'1 minutes'),column1 , column2,  column3....column_n `

Comment: The dataframe has all topics along with their own timestamps in one, so if you need to join anything, you'd start with filter function to extract different topics to a new dataframe.. Also, don't use cartesian joins

Comment: okay so I have to it in similar way which I have done for one topic I.e create multiple dataframe and then use SQL

Comment: That's the only way I can think of. Someone else might have a better idea.